# When adding property to a class by adding it in a category, getting "unrecognized selector..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category

I tried to expand on SKSpriteNode, and tried several ways to do it (by has-a relationship in a new class, by extending it directly), finally I want to try to do it using categories. So, I make a category the proper way in XCode, using the assistant, and choose SKSpriteNode as the class for the category. I expand on the existing class and make a new file with additional methods and properties named SKSpriteNode+StaticLevelElement.h and SKSpriteNode+StaticLevelElement.m. For some reason, I can't add properties. I tried

1. Adding the setter and getter methods for the new properties in the category's .m file, and still I get the message "unrecognized selector sent to instance".
2. Adding @dynamic in front of each new property in the category implementation, same result as above.
3. Tried setting **Other linker flags** in build settings, got same result as above.
4. Tried using associated objects (http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html), same result.

Any suggestions guys? I would love to use categories, and I still don't want to give up on the, since I see how cool they can be, working with sprites inside XCode visual editor, and not only programatically, makes it very easy to see the result directly, and not having to extend classes and do everything programatically, and hope for a good look and feel of the game.

Relevant code:

```
//  SKSpriteNode+StaticLevelElement.m
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "SKSpriteNode+StaticLevelElement.h"

NSString * const gamePlayLogicSelector = @"gamePlayLogic";
NSString * const pseudoDepthSelector = @"pseudoDepth";

@implementation SKSpriteNode (StaticLevelElement)

@dynamic gamePlayLogic;
@dynamic pseudoDepth;
@dynamic theName;
@dynamic gameScene;


- (void)setPseudoDepth:(float)pd
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(pseudoDepthSelector), pd, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}
```

Last line causes error "passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Associated objects is the correct way to do it.  You should add the code showing your attempt.

Comment: Agree w/@dan; also, the association policy (last parameter to `objc_setAssociatedObject()`) should **probably** be `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` instead of `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY`, but YMMV; you should read up on that parameter a bit to make sure you get the right semantics for your situation.

Comment: I actually switched the float property to NSNumber and it seems to work now, per the tutorial for associated objects. Now another problem occurs, some other SKSpriteNode-s just disappeared, I NSLogged them and it seems they exist but size is 0,0.....The objects are also added in scene editor the visual editor.

Comment: Changing to `NSNumber` works because you are using associated *objects* and that is an object type. However `float` is a value type, or POD (plain old data type) in C-ese and not an object. As to your other problem it sounds like you need to ask a new question. HTH

Comment: So you have just formulated same question as I have. How to add a POD property to a category? Any suggestion on this? Thanks!

Comment: @CRD thanks, posted new question about disappearing sprites here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974247/texture-for-sprite-not-found-and-sprite-not-displayed-when-using-unarchivefromfi

Comment: Do almost what you did - use `NSNumber` or `NSValue` - but keep the POD type in the signature and do the (un)wrapping within the setter/getter

Comment: As @CRD said, just wrap pd in @() when passing it to objc_setAssociatedObject